# How to get wishlist product details on wishlist_product_add_after event in magento2

Tags: magento2, products, wishlist

How to get `wishlist` product details on `wishlist_product_add_after` event in **magento2**.
Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps to get current product details on wishlist_product_add_after event in magento2

Step 1 : Add event in **etc/event.xml** file.

```
<event name="wishlist_product_add_after">
    <observer instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Customer\Custom" name="wishlist_product_add_after_custom"/>
</event>
```

Step 2 : Create Custom.php event Observer file on the location Vendor/ModuleName/Observer/Customer/Custom.php and add below code on this file

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Customer;

class Custom implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $type;

    protected $productFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $type
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $items = $observer->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
            $wishlist_item = $item->getBuyRequest();

            $supper = $wishlist_item->getSuperAttribute();
            $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($wishlist_item->getProduct());
            $product->getSku();

            if ($product->getTypeId()=="configurable") {
                if (!empty($supper)) {
                    $simple = $this->type->getProductByAttributes($supper,$product);
                    $simple->getSku();
                }
            }
            $item->getQty();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me it worked.  @saneer-ladani